# Remove purchased apps front Appstore

Tags: ios-appstore

I downloaded a whole bunch of apps for iPhone, and then deleted them.

But they are still associated with my account, and when I go back to the download page, I don't see the `[GET]` button, but the iCloud logo...

I want to get rid of that, and it seem that Apple has change the way it could be done before.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've bought it [whether paid or free] it's yours forever.
You can delete purchases from all devices, but you still retain the right to download it again in future.

The cloud icon signifies that you can redownload it at any time.

Comment: It was previously possible to remove a purchased app. We just had to go to our account through iTunes, go to the purchased apps and click the delete button. The app was correctly deleted (not hidden). This is the feature I'm looking for now.

Comment: You can swipe left in the Purchased list to hide it

Comment: Swiping from left to right, or right to left has no effect.